# Eclipse: Error in final launch sequence Failed to execute MI command

Tags: c++, eclipse

When I try to debug the HelloWorld C++ application, I get the following error. The `gdb` specified in the debug configuration for HelloWorld looks correct. What's up?

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 43655: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 43655: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and I don't know how to fix it either, I signed gdb with my own cert, and it's still not working and I don't have a clue what's wrong.